# First Spring4 MVC Attempt not loading with Tomcat 7

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-java-config

Im fairly new to spring mvc and Im trying to launch a extremely simple project that will just display a greeting on a blank page but for some reason I cannot seem to get it to run on the tomcat server, I have gone over every little piece of code and I do not believe there are any mistakes as well as made sure that the tomcat server is configured correctly, any help anyone can give me would be appreciated (This isn't any kind of assignment for anything , this is purely for me trying to learn Spring MVC and learning the proper configuration, because after researching for hours I cannot find anything wrong with it)

I also did this purely in java, no xml. Did not use any dependency managers either  ( No Maven or Gradle ) but I do have all necessary jars

I first start by configuring the dispatcher servlet and pass it the webConfig so that the application context can load beans via component scan, since this is a simple project I have no RootConfig class
[image]

In my WebConfig I enable Spring MVC ,I give ComponentScan the base package that will search for all Controller classes to create beans for the application context and I create a simple view resolver that will wrap view names with the specified prefix and suffix

[image]

My Controller again is really simple I annotate the class as the default handler for "/" requests and map the sayHello method to handle requests for "/home" where I attach a simple message to the model(map) and return the view name

[image]

And finally my view which displays the message, The tags in the header of the jsp I know are useless since I'm not using any tags in the form they are just something left over from a previous attempt

[image]

When I run this application on the tomcat server I get the following, Im running Tomcat 7 which does support spring mvc java configuration

[image]

The tomcat server is running properly

[image]

Project is in the webapps directory of tomcat server 
[image]

And to the best of my knowledge the server configurations are correct

[image]

[image]

[image]

Console output 
[image]

[image]

### - Solution -

As mentioned below in the comments the warning I got was

[image]

SpringProjLibs is a user library I created and placed all my spring jars inside

This comment along with some research on this warning led me to realize I had failed to  add the library to the deployment assembly like below (the entry highlighted in blue was not there , I added that) after adding the line in blue it solved that problem

[image]

### IMPORTANT

Im adding a follow up to this post since this still pertains to my original question. After completing the above step it resolved THAT issue but another issue presented itself.

I got the following error and tomcat failed to launch

> Jun 18, 2018 5:57:37 PM
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
>   SEVERE: Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in
>   class
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration:
>   Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Factory method [public
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.requestMappingHandlerAdapter()]
>   threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'mvcValidator' defined in class
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/classmate/Filter

After doing some research I discovered that contrary to what ive studied and seen in online material the annotations @EnableWebMvc and @ComponentScan together in the WebConfig class were causing this issue. I resolved this issue by moving the @EnableWebMvc annotation to the Initializer class , now my classes look like the following

[image]

[image]

This resolved all my issues and my project launched successfully

[image]

Comment: Are you launching Tomcat from within Eclipse?

Comment: Im launching from within eclipse @Otomatonium

Comment: Are you launching it like this: Right-click SimpleMVC project -> Run As... -> Run on Server ?

Comment: Yes I am @Otomatonium

Comment: Hmmm. The code looks alright, but one thing that's missing from your console output that I usually see when I run Spring MVC is info messages given by org.springframework.*. One thing to look at also is the cause(s) of the warning symbol on the project icon.

Comment: @Otomatonium your comment about the warning led me to a solution I will post my solution for the record above.